# Watson Conversation get the first key of every element of an array

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson-assistant

I am currently working on a chatbot based on IBM Watson conversations. 
And I'm struggling getting the key out of the `enginePower` in the filter.
I need every key to be displayed in the chat. So a user can select one.

The structure looks like that:

```js
"filter": {
"enginePower": [{
            "key": "55",
            "text": "55 kW (75 PS)",
            "selectable": false
          },
          {
            "key": "65",
            "text": "65 kW (88 PS)",
            "selectable": false
          },
          {
            "key": "66",
            "text": "66 kW (90 PS)",
            "selectable": false
          },
          {
            "key": "81",
            "text": "81 kW (110 PS)",
            "selectable": false
          }]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the dialog backend or the application layer?

Comment: @akaykay I am doing it right in a slot.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
Your key values are: <? T(String).join( ",", $filter.get('enginePower').![key] ) ?>
```

***Broken down***

`$filter.get('enginePower')`

This will return the enginePower as an array containing all your objects.

`.![key]`

This will return the "Key" field values as an array.

`T(String).join( ",", XXX )`

This will convert your array XXX into a comma delimited list.

So your final output will say:

```
Your key values are: 55,65,66,81
```

---

Just to add to this. You can only get a single key/value list. If you want to capture a value of a different attribute using a key lookup, then you need to loop.

So for example, start by setting a `counter` to `0`. Then have your node check for `$filter.enginePower.size() > $counter`.

Within that node, you set "multiple responses" on. Then for the first condition you set `$filter.enginePower[$counter].selectable == true`. This will allow you to take action if that field is true.

After this you need to create a child node, and have the parent node jump to it. Within the child node response put `<? $counter = $counter + 1 ?>`. Lastly have the child node jump back to the parent node.

This will loop through the array. **Warning!** You can only loop 50 times before the loop will end. This is to stop potential endless loops.

---

Realistically though, you can easily solve all this by formatting the data correctly at the application layer.